# Help me optimise this 2-line Javascript, if possible!

Tags: javascript, optimization, dependencies, inline

I have a 2-liner here which... does the trick, but its just a bit lame looking really:

```
var n = 'configOb_'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
while( document[n] !== undefined ){ n = 'configOb_'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100); }
```

It's basically generating a unique id. It's important to note that I cannot use any JS dependency files, as this script is executed before my `YUILoader` instance finishes up (the above script is located within `<body />`, YUILoader waits for DOM readiness).

So what I'm after is any clever optimisations of the above 2-liner.

Thanks!

Edit: Er, sorry, I did select that as code - but it isn't holding... hopefully this time...

Comment: Are you executing lots of these in a loop? Why not just start at "configOb_0" and increment from there? An algorithms person would tell you that your algorithm will start having trouble finding "holes" randomly as you fill up the namespace.

Comment: Optimisation for _what_ exactly? Size, I don't think it's needed. Speed, it's hard to imagine it's needed. As an aside, why the fixed constant 100. Can you not work out how many `configOb_*` elements there are and use that? What happens if there's 212 of them? This approach seems ... tortured to me, from a general algorithmic viewpoint.

Comment: Good questions, here's a bit more context: A chunk of HTML is dropped into a document during creation. The doc scans and finds these chunks. When a chunk is found, it has a nested script element containing the above 2-liner. The scanner then augments the config object props onto an instantiated module. So, by optimisation I mean "Can this be tidier?" and so long as one 'html chunk' doesn't need to know or worry about another code chunk - then I'm good to go. This is a change from an old system, so there's probably a bunch of stuff I *could* do, keeping things compact will do for now.

Comment: Also, sorry ran out of chars - there won't be more than... 10 chunks on a doc. If there's 30ish (like my test page), then I still haven't run into any performance issues.

Comment: yes, but why randomly select them ? or do you want this to be in sequence ?

Comment: `var n = 0; while(!document['configOb_'+(n++)]){}` ?

Comment: @david, does that also need a `n--` at the end? I think it would increment `n` even when the free slot was found.

Comment: true, it should have been ++n!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't stated what you want it optimised for, speed or size but I'll optimise it for correctness if you wish :-)

As you approach the 100-object limit, the running time for that loop is going to get longer and longer, right up to the point where you've used all the objects, when it will become infinite.

I would just start at 0 and go up until you find a free slot, something like:

```
var n = 0;
while (document['configOb_' + n] !== undefined ) {
    n = n + 1;
}
n = 'configOb_' + n;
```

Of course, you're still limited, but it's well beyond the 100 bound that your random function gives you. In addition, the run time will still increase as the number of objects increases but at least in a more deterministic way.

Comment: Note that the recommended way of testing whether something is not undefined in JavaScript is: `(typeof foo !== "undefined")`

Comment: @Šime, that just shows how little I know of JS :-) I was approaching it more from an algorithm perspective.

Comment: @Sime, unless you define undefined as undefined.

Comment: @box9 The `undefined` global property initially does hold the `undefined` value. The problem is that one can replace that value by simple assignment: `undefined = false;`. If such an assignment would occur, the above code would become an infinite loop.

Comment: @paxdiablo I am amazed how much score you got for all these different languages: C, C++, Java, C#, Python, SQL, PHP, Perl, etc. :D

Comment: @Sime, which is why I suggested defining undefined in the local scope, e.g. `(function(undefined){/* code here... */})()`. Sure, not necessary but I thought I'd point it out ;)

Comment: Ok paxdiablo - the Q goes to you, my thinking cap is just not on at this time of year. Obviously I should be starting from 0, and thank you Šime for the typeof reminder. But you're all quite right, so thank you everyone :D

Comment: WHOA! @Šime  --  adding in typeof causes infinite recursion on this script! I'm using paxdiablo + yours:  var n = 0; while(typeof document['configOb_' + n] !== undefined) {n+=1;} n = 'configOb_' + n;

Comment: @Danjah You're using it wrong. `undefined` has to be in quotes: `typeof ... !== "undefined"`. That's because the `typeof` operator always returns a string value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from "but its just a bit lame looking" that you're after code neatness rather than any real "optimization", then since `document[undefined] === undefined`, you can just do:

```
var n;
while( document[n] !== undefined ){ n = 'configOb_'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100); }
```

Or alternatively, a do..while loop makes more sense:

```
var n;
do { n = 'configOb_'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100); } while (document[n] !== undefined);
```

If you're really after speed optimization, then firstly, if a random number isn't necessary (just unique), then increment `n` from 0. If you must use random numbers, increase the multiplier from `100` so you have a lower chance of getting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want to accomplish but here you go

```
var n;    
while( document[ n='configOb_'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100) ] !== undefined );
```